Content script not loading for custom file type
Lets say for example .custom. Whenever I am opening the file with extensions .custom, it should open in Chrome and the content script should load. How to implement this? I have added the code below, since .custom file is not recognized by Chrome, its downloaded. How to resolve this issue?

This is the code for manifest.json file
"content_scripts": [{
"matches": [
"http:///",
"https:///",
"ftp:///",
"file:///"
],
"run_at": "document_start",
"all_frames": true,
"js": ["contentscript.js"]
}],
"content_security_policy": {
"extension_pages": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'"
},
"file_browser_handlers": [{
"id": "open-as-image",
"default_title": "Open with Custom Viewer",
"file_filters": [
"filesystem:*.custom"
]
}],

You need to add a declarativeNetRequest rule for urlFilter: '.custom|' and action that sets Content-Type header to text/html, then your content script should run.

Hi @woxxom, thanks for the quick response. My Content type is image/cgm, I tried the same logic but its not triggering content script instead the file is getting downloaded
